# Difference betwen these two ways of creating objects of arrays

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {};
obj.arr1 = [];
obj.arr2 = [];
```

// Does the above one create a new object each time.

```
var obj = {
  obj.arr1 = [],
  obj.arr2 = []
};
```

Comment: second code not working)

Answer (score 3):

Except for the syntax error, the two means of creating the object will give you the exact same result. In your second example, what you're thinking of is probably this:

```
var obj = {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: []
};
```

I'm not sure what you mean with regards to creating a new object each time. In both examples of the code, the value variable `obj` will be set to a new object with two empty arrays. If there was already an `obj` object in that context, with one or more arrays, they would be overwritten.

Comment: The problem here for me is, object in the context is holding the same array across the application... the value inside the array remains same...

Comment: @theJava: It's not clear what you're asking. `var obj = { ... }` will create a new object and assign that to the `obj` variable every time, regardless of what's between the curly brackets, or if nothing is between them at all. If you're trying to overwrite, but getting old values when you're trying to access, then you're doing something else wrong. Either a mistyped name (casing issue perhaps?), the code you think you're executing is not being executed or you're not in the closure you think you are, or something like that. We cannot tell from just the code you've included so far.

Answer (score 0):

> // Does the above one create a new object each time.

No.
And the too ways is almost the same.

And second way is not right, should be

```
var obj = {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: []
};
```

> How can i create a new object each time

If you mean the array object `[]`, yes they are already different objects. `obj.arr1` and `obj.arr2` is not same object. `obj.arr1 === obj.arr2` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine in the first way the array is created and in the later step it adds the element by creating memory location ...where as in second methodology the array is created and the elements of it also created then and there itself. (I imagine diff is the time of creation of memory locations for the array elements may vary)

Comment: The question is about JavaScript... why have you linked to the PHP documentation?

Comment: @James Allardice admitted, changed